# How to use pim protocol to configure a multicast tree in frrouting

Tags: pim, igmp

How to use pim protocol to configure a multicast tree in frrouting, the router and host use Ubuntu20 version instead, I tried for a long time igmp can not find the host to join, hope to get your help

The igmp router I configured in routing is
Gi0-4-0 interface ip address is 192.10.1.1
interface Gi0-4-0
ip igmp
ip igmp version 2
ip igmp query-interval 10

Is configured on the host that receives multicast traffic:
Gi0-6-0 interface ip address is 192.100.1.1
interface Gi0-6-0
ip igmp
ip igmp join 224.1.1.1 192.100.1.1
ip igmp version 2

I check the igmp group on the igmp side of the router
r1# show ip igmp groups
Total IGMP groups: 0
Watermark warn limit(Not Set): 0
Interface        Group           Mode Timer    Srcs V Uptime

The host group is
r2# show ip igmp groups
Total IGMP groups: 1
Watermark warn limit(Not Set): 0
Interface        Group           Mode Timer    Srcs V Uptime
Gi0-6-0          224.1.1.1       ---- 00:02:42    1 2 00:52:00